# Faster search in Lucene - Is there a way to keep the whole index in RAM?

Tags: search, lucene, full-text-indexing

Is there a way of keeping the index in RAM instead of keeping it on the hard disk?

We want to make searching faster.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is there a way of keeping the index in RAM instead of keeping it on the hard disk?

Using the **[RAMDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html)** class

SampleUsage **[here](http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/)**

Also from the Lucene FAQs

**[ImproveSearchingSpeed](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed)**

*Generally for faster indexing performance it's best to flush by RAM usage instead of document count and use as large a RAM buffer as you can.*

**[Also check this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673887/using-ramdirectory)**

**EDIT:** **RE: RamDirectory**, As the API says RamDirectory is **A memory-resident Directory implementation.**, it keeps only those index in RAM as specified by directory **[RAMDirecory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2%5F4%5F0/api/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html#RAMDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory))**

**RE:Caching**  In my knowledge, Lucene caches search results by means of  filters pls look @ [CachingWrapperFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/CachingWrapperFilter.html) and [QueryWrapperFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/QueryWrapperFilter.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have two further questions. 


First, I read that Lucene does caching, which would be keeping the index partially in RAM. But the RAMDirectory is different, right? Does it keep all of the index in the RAM? 


Second, I saw the setRAMBufferSizeMB, what I understood was that it was for speeding up the indexing rather than searching. Does it also speed up searching?

Comment: From "ImproveSearchingSpeed": "Open the IndexReader with readOnly=true", do you know how to do this in Lucene 4+? I couldn't find any examples...

Answer (score 1):

A RAM disk could be a solution for this. A mini-HOWTO is available at http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html. Mount the RAM disk as your index directory, and you should be done.

Comment: Note that for large indexes, "hardware" RAM disks are also available... basically device with a hard drive interface, but filled with DRAM instead of platters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We considered that. But we tend not to use that option as we don't have that much experience in the operating system. We think that it would give us less control and less ability to observe/monitor the index.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [RAMDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html) documentation. Here's a [basic usage example](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/TheBasics). This will only work if the index is small enough.

Comment: And thank you for answering.

What size would be small?

The index is about 20 MB's and we don't expect it to grow more than 5 times. Is this small enough?

Comment: You're welcome. A 100 MB is indeed small enough. You should still consider using a disk index with proper JVM stack size settings. This will save you having to re-index whenever you restart the application, and may be as fast as the RAMDirectory. See also:
http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Scaling-Lucene-and-Solr about search speed.

Comment: Why does it reindex when I restart the application? I thought I could read the index on the hard disk into the RAM using RAMDirectory. Do I have to reindex everytime I want to read the index into the RAM?
Thank you for the link.

Comment: You are right. You can read it from the hard disk:
http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html#RAMDirectory%28java.io.File%29